# Passing parameters in a jQuery ajax call to an ASP.NET webmethod

Tags: jquery, json, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I know there are more threads about this but they dont help me and I'm going insane here!

I wanna pass some parameters in to a web method using jQuery Ajax.

```
var paramList = '';
for(i = 0; i < IDList.length; i++){
    if (paramList.length > 0) paramList += ',';  
        paramList += '"' + 'id' + '":"' + IDList[i].value + '"';  
    }
    paramList = '{' + paramList + '}';  
    var jsonParams = JSON.stringify(paramList);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",          
        url: "editactivity.aspx/UpdateSequenceNumber",          
        data: jsonParams,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {

        }
    });
```

In the ajax call, if I put data to paramList I get the error: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027a\u0027."

If I put data to jsonParams I get the error:

> "Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type
>   \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\u0027"

If I write out `paramList`, it's in a correct JSON format like `{"id":"140", "id":"138"}`

If I write out `jsonParams`, it's in an incorrect format like `"{\"id\":\"140\",\"id\":\"138\"}"`

The web method: (it doesn't do that much yet..)

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string UpdateSequenceNumber(string a, string b)
    {
         return a+b;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Can't seem to get this JSON thing right.

**UPDATE:**

After some help from the first answer I now send `{"id":["138","140"]}` in the AJAX request.

The web method now takes a string called `id` as the parameter instead.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string UpdateSequenceNumber(string id)
{
     return id;
}
```

Now I get the new error:

> "Type \u0027System.Array\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of
>   an array."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your json parameter names must be same with the c# paramter names.

```
{"a":"140", "b":"138"}
```

If you are sending unknown number of parameters to server, you may concat at client-side into one parameter and then split at server-side.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know that.

Now after I do 

var c = JSON.stringify({"id":list});

I get: {"id":["138","140"]} which looks alright. But know i get a new error when doing the ajax request:

"Type \u0027System.Array\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array."

Comment: I didn't know that we can use List type as c# datatype with webmethod, thanks ;)

Comment: Glad we could help each other :)

Comment: @larschanders i'm still getting upvotes but why don't u accept this as an answer? :)

Comment: Guys I have this same issue but It didn't resolve it. Does anyone know if the jQuery could cause this problem?